# google sheets search for a value from bottom to up

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i have a google sheet with sales values per day. i want to calculate week over week change of sales change. Change between every working Monday to previous working Monday. If the Monday is holiday sales row for that monday is not present in the data. please check the sample sales sheet image.

i tried VLOOKUP with 1/RANGE, LOOKUP with 1/RANGE but nothing is working for me. as shown in the example 28-Nov-2022 to 14-Nov-2022 skips monday on 21-Nov-2022.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate about XLOOKUP: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12405947?hl=en

You can set your match mode to find the lower or upper value if not found and the search mode from up to down or vice versa

Comment: i tried LOOKUP, VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP but missed XLOOKUP. thanks for your pointer solved my problem.